# Inserting a page into a word document?

Tags: c#, ms-word, vsto

I am doing VSTO development using C# creating a Word add-in. I was wondering how I can go about inserting two pages (one before the active document at the very beginning and one at the end of the active document at the very end)?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Range.InsertBreak](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/Word.Range.InsertBreak) method which inserts a page, column, or section break. When you insert a section break, the break is inserted immediately preceding the Range.

```
Set pag = ActiveDocument.GoTo(wdGoToPage, wdGoToAbsolute, i)
pag.InsertBreak WdBreakType.wdPageBreak
```

where `i` represents the page number.